# How to use generic annotations like @Transient in an entity shared between Mongo and Elastic Search in Spring?

Tags: spring, mongodb, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot and sharing the same entity between an Elastic Search database and a MongoDB database. The entity is declared this way:

```
@Document
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName =  "...", type = "...", createIndex = true)
public class ProcedureStep {
...
}
```

Where `@Document` is from this package: `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document`

This works without any issue, but I am not able to use generic annotations to target Elastic Search only. For example:

```
@Transient
private List<Point3d> c1s, c2s, c3s, c4s;
```

This will exclude this field from both databases, Mongo and Elastic, whereas my intent was to apply it for Elastic Search only.

I have no issue in using Elastic specific annotations like this:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
private String studyDescription;
```

My question is:
what annotation can I use to exclude a field from Elastic Search only and keep it in Mongo?
I don't want to rewrite the class as I don't have a "flat" structure to store (the main class is composed with fields from other classes, which themselves have fields I want to exclude from Elastic)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** ObjectMapper is used for Serialization/Deserialization

> My question is: what annotation can I use to exclude a field from
> Elastic Search only and keep it in Mongo? I don't want to rewrite the
> class as I don't have a "flat" structure to store (the main class is
> composed with fields from other classes, which themselves have fields
> I want to exclude from Elastic)

1. Please understand this is a problem of selective serialization.
2. It can be achieved using [JsonViews](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).

**Example:**

**Step1:** Define 2 views, ES Specific & MongoSpecific.

```
class Views {
public static class MONGO {};
public static class ES {};
```

}

**Step2:** Annotate the fields as below. Description as comments :

```
@Data
class Product {
    private int id;     // <======= Serialized for both DB & ES Context
    
    @JsonView(Views.ES.class) //<======= Serialized for ES Context only
    private float price;
    
    @JsonView(Views.MONGO.class) // <======= Serialized for MONGO Context only
    private String desc;
}
```

**Step 3:**

Configure Different Object Mappers for Spring-Data-ES & Mongo.

```
// Set View for MONGO
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.MONGO.class));

// Set View for ES
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.ES.class));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and upvote if it is helpful